# Upload a large video

Tags: nginx, wordpress, video, audio

I have bought a dedicated server from DigitalOcean and built a website using WordPress. I have a video of 822Mb; I want to add this video to a page of my website such that visitors can directly watch this video on the page.

It seems that the steps to follow are:

1. upload the video to the server, and get a URL
2. add a video player plugin of WordPress, which permits of playing the video from the URL.

If this is the right approach, my question is about the first step:

- how to upload an 822Mb video
- where to put it (`/var/www/wordpress/html/wp-content/uploads/` ?)
- what will be its URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upload your video via sftp, ftp or ssh. Move the video on a place with access/read permissions on the server... 
if your main site on the www.mydomain.com is /var/www/wordpress/ put the file on this directory. The URL is like www.mydomain.com/video.mp4.
all depends of the directory permission on your site (ngix configuration).